# Do this using bit operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want eval if a integer number between 0 and 255 is equal to 0 or equal to 224.

I have this code:

```
if (!num || 224 == num)
```

Is there a way for do this using some bitwise operation?

I tried this and I have valid: 0, 31, 32, 63 ,64, 95, 96, 127, 128, 159, 160, 191, 192, 223, 224, 255. Obvious is bad because I only need 0 and 224.

```
!((num+1) & 30)
```

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: Why? It is already using quick operations and more importantly it is readable

Comment: The standard place to go for bit twiddling hacks is [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).  I'm not sure whether it covers cases like this, though.

Comment: I post one of my tries.

Comment: I forgive specify that the num is always between 0 and 255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and the range of the input makes it slightly easier.

You can use `(x - 1) >> 31` to detect whether `x` is 0 (technically not portable, but will usually work)

It relies on `x` never being already smaller than 0, and, non-portably, on right shift on a signed int being an arithmetic shift (which is usually the case).

Similarly, you can use `((x ^ 224) - 1) >> 31` to detect 224.

Just put them together like this:

```
int mask = ((x - 1) >> 31) | (((x ^ 224) - 1) >> 31);
```

And there you go.

Answer (score 0):

`abs(2x-A) == A` comes to mind (where A is your constant of 224), but `abs()` is likely doing a compare inside and subtraction is hardly a bit operation.  What exactly are you trying to do, it is for speed or just curiosity?

Another idea is modulus `x%A == 0`, but this will also return true for all multiples of A.  (448,672,...)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is for curiosity trying found a way more speedy.

Comment: sorry, but i don't understand, what is A ? 2x means 2 * ?

Comment: You can do `abs` in a couple of bitwise operations too, by the way

Comment: A is 224, your constant.  Was your question specific to the number 224?  I approached the question as a generic constant...

Answer (score -2):

```
if (!num^0x3F) {
  // a little less readable
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  This program: `#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    for (int num = 0; num < 256; num++)
        if (!num^0x3F)
            printf("%d\n", num);
    return(0);
}` lists all 256 numbers 0..255.  If the expression is written `if (!(num^0x3F))`, it lists just 63.